# Two minicom instances talk to each other on same machine

Tags: serial-port, minicom

Is it possible to have two instances of minicom on the same machine talking to each other? If so, what device/port should be used, and how should it be set up?

I tried opening minicom in two different instances Bash shell and pointing both to /dev/tty2. The first instance opens fine, but the second instance says that device is locked.

Comment: when i remove the lock file, i don't see anything typed in the first instance, on the second instance

Comment: Here's a way to do it with socat: [Virtual serial port for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19733677/2554472)